# Getting different value for ps command when assigning to a variable

Tags: shell-script, ps, echo, command-substitution

I get a different output when I assign this to a variable. Why is this?

```
#!/bin/bash
P=$(ps -ef | grep ${APP} | grep -v grep  | wc -l)
echo ps -ef | grep ${APP} | grep -v grep  | wc -l
echo $P
```

Output:

```
0
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second command is flawed in that you are not actually executing `ps -ef`, instead you are echoing the literal string `ps -ef`.  You then `grep` for a specific string that does not exist in the string `ps -ef` and counting how many lines are returned, which is `0`.

You could simply do:

```
P=$(ps -ef | grep "${APP}" | grep -v grep  | wc -l)
ps -ef | grep "${APP}" | grep -v grep  | wc -l
echo "$P"
```

---

Or as Jeff has pointed out this would be more simple with `pgrep` (where available):

```
p=$(pgrep "${APP}" | wc -l)
pgrep "${APP}" | wc -l
echo "$p"
```

Comment: If: Linux, Then: Suggest `pgrep`

Comment: seems at least [FreeBSD has pgrep too](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pgrep&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

Comment: macos and sunos as well

Comment: ... and OpenBSD.